# Ensure that the export of multiple files is atomic

Tags: c++, export

I have to implement an exporter library in C++, that can format and export different kinds of data to different kinds of file formats (csv, xml, ...).

Each export may consists of a bunch of files and directories:

```
data
|-- person
|    |-- joepublic 
|    |    +-- File1.xml
|    |    +-- Annotation.csv
|    |    +-- Annotation2.csv
|    |-- mrsmith
|    |    +-- Balance.bin
```

Now it might happen under a multitude of circumstances that the export fails in one of these files. Let's assume, that I was unable to write Balance.bin, as the format was incorrect or I ran out of disk space.

Now I'm left with an inconsistent set of files, that might crash another application while reading them.

How can I prevent myself from such inconsistent exports and at the same time reduce the amount of necessary code. Are there some standard procedures or libraries around?

My first attempt for a solution would be to export all files firstly to the temp directory and after successfully writing them to move them to the correct target directory.

Comment: You could create the directory as `work_in_progress` and rename it `data` when complete. That would save you from moving all the files (which could also potentially fail).

Comment: Good suggestion. But as the library is fairly general one could not assume that there are directories at all. One could also export to just one existing directory already containing files.

Comment: if you're using a single thread, why not simply monitor as each file is written, and if you encounter a failure, stop and remove what you did (if that's the cleanup method)?

Comment: Basically, that would be the method. And seemingly there is no way to magically automatize this behavior. As for a database one has the concept of transactions, that is missing for such simple things like writing to files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the OS provides no way to atomically link operations on multiple files. There are [a few things](http://rcrowley.org/2010/01/06/things-unix-can-do-atomically.html) that some OS can provide however (note that this is not guaranteed on all OS).

The simplest is clearly to put all the files in a directory and then to rename or move it.

Another option is to have a file serving as a marker `finished` as part of your content. It would be some kind of lock: before any write operation, you would remove it and after you're finished, you create it. If it's not there, it means the content is potentially not readable so you do not read it.

I agree this may look awkward but this is what Microsoft Word`*` is doing`**` when it opens a file`***`.

```
  * I let you decide if it's a good reference
 ** or used to do
*** at least on CIFS volumes
```

Comment: That seems to be a possible way to do it. Many thanks, I'll try it as soon as possible.